# Describe the interior and boundary of the calculus function.

Tags: calculus

We were given this example in a lecture, however we ran out of time to explain it. I have a test coming up and would appreciate if someone could give the direction to start solving the question. Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: ask your instructor at the start of the next lecture. As a start sketch the line x+y=1, also sketch x-y=1, keep sketching.